# Infeasible for simple binary matrix using cplex and yalmip

Tags: matlab, cplex

I'm getting start with cplex and yalmip. I got a 'Integer infeasible column 'x2'.' for the code below.

```
N = 2;
O = binvar(N,N);
F = [];
for i = 1:N
    for j = 1:N
        if i ==j
            F = F + (O(i,i) ==0);
        else
            F = F+ (O(i,j) + O(j,i) ==1);
        end
    end
end

optimize(F);
diagnostics =  optimize(F);
if diagnostics.problem == 0
    disp('Feasible');
elseif diagnostics.problem == 1
    disp('Infeasible');
else
    disp('Something else happened');
    disp(diagnostics.problem);
end
```

I'm not sure what's wrong here.... The constraints looks quite feasible to me?

Answer (score 0):

Square matrices are symmetric by default, hence your model is infeasible
https://yalmip.github.io/tutorial/basics/

YALMIP-specific questions are much better addressed on YALMIP specific forums
https://github.com/yalmip/YALMIP/discussions

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/yalmip